# Best Practices when using JPA and detach()

Tags: jpa, entitymanager, detach

I'm using the following JPA entity:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "FOO")
public class Foo {

    @Id @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    // getters/setters ommited for brevity
}
```

I have a service class that performs some validations and persists instances of this class (assume that _entityManager is one-per-request):

```
public static Foo save( Foo f ) {
    if ( f.getName().length() > 4 )
                    throw new RuntimeException("Name is too big");
    _entityManager.persist(f);
    return f;
}
```

Calling the service works as expected:

```
// works
_entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
save( new Foo(1, "One") );
_entityManager.getTransaction().commit();   

// fails
_entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
save( new Foo(2, "Large") );
_entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

However, it is a JPA feature that changes to an object pass-through to the database (at the end of the transaction, maybe earlier). Thus, I can write:

```
_entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    Foo f = FooService.save( new Foo( 1, "One" ) );
Foo g = _entityManager.find(Foo.class, 1);
g.setName("Large");
_entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

The problem is that by modifying the object outside of the service implementation, developers can inadvertently bypass all validation.

I understand this is less of a problem if your database has constraints, or if you have annotations on Foo that validate input. But, what if there are constraints that are not database-enforceable? Or that require external information and may not be written as annotations?

At my project, we have been using a rule-of-thumb: every public service that returns an Entity must detach() it first. This way, changes will not be persisted. However, that makes service composition harder. For example:

```
Foo f = FooService.findById(1); // returns detached instance
Bar b = new Bar();
f.getBars().add(b);
b.setFoo(f);
```

Since the returned Foo is detached, adding to its list of Bars does nothing to the real, entity-managed Foo. Thus, attempts to (for instance) delete(f) will fail because the entity manager won't even know there are child instances to delete first.

Has anyone encountered this situation before? Are there any best practices regarding this subject?

Comment: Use unit & integration tests to validate the logic. Also make sure public setters do not allow setting entity to invalid state. You could also do validation on prepersist & preupdate events